# Is there an option to remove points from an existing line in kivy using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

A straightforward way to add a line is to use:

```
line.ud["line"].points += [touch.x, touch.y]
```

I want to ask if I can remove points from a line. What I actually want to do is to make a line which moves as mouse moves.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose tho `points` are a list of lists.

To simplify, I will immitate your points structure with `points` variable.

1. you can remove specified point (must be in the list)

   ```
   points = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]
   points.remove([3,4])
   print(points)  # [[1,2], [5,6]]
   ```
2. You can pop an `i`-th point in the list

   ```
   points = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]
   removed_point = points.pop(1)  
   print(removed_point)  # [3,4] 
   print(points)  # [[1,2], [5,6]]
   ```
3. You can slice the list to get rid of the unwanted points

   ```
   points = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]
   points = points[:1] + points[2:]
   print(points)  # [[1,2], [5,6]]
   ```